# .NET Session not working

Tags: asp.net, session-state

This is a weird one, but hopefully someone can give me an idea here. I'm putting a few values into session in the `Session_Start` of the `Global.asax` in my app. Immediately after the `Session_Start` my base page's `OnInit` gets called and tries to use one of those `Session` variables.

The weird part is sometimes it works, and then after NO changes will start giving me this error:

> "Session state can only be used when
>   `enableSessionState` is set to `true`,
>   either in a configuration file or in
>   the `Page` directive. Please also make
>   sure that
>   `System.Web.SessionStateModule` or a
>   custom session state module is
>   included in the
>   `<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>`
>   section in the application
>   configuration."

I've looked and looked finding all different ways on enabling session in the `web.config`. Here is what it looks like now:

```
<system.web>
...
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>

    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
    <pages>
    <!-- enableSessionState="true" autoEventWireup="true" enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" -->
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
        <!--<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>-->
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

You can see I have some stuff commented out, specifically the `enableSessionState="true"` and `<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>` because they were never there before and it always used to work. But I've tried it with them both enabled, one or the other enabled, it just doesn't make a difference.

This is an app that has been in production for years, I'm only making minor changes, probably the biggest of which is adding a "titlebar" page to it, and upgrading from 2.0 to 3.5. I haven't tried adding the `enableSessionState` to the page directives because it didn't work in the `web.config` I don't see why it would work directly on the page, and I'd hate to dirty the app up anymore or waste anymore time trying in vain to enable session.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Are you running this in IIS 6 or IIS 7?

Comment: Locally IIS6, on test & production IIS7.

Comment: Is this failing in both IIS6 and IIS7?

Comment: locally (IIS6) it fails immediately. In test it's fine until I change who I'm logged in as which may or may not be a seperate issue, but since I can't test that one until I get this one fixed I'm running it locally so I can figure this one out :(

Comment: You probably don't need stateConnectionString or sqlConnectionString in your sessionState node.  I'm sure that's not causing your problem, though...

Comment: I've also tried removing those to no avail.

Comment: How long does it take before the app is unable to access the session values?

Comment: To be honest, ASP.NET doesn't really need the <sessionState> declaration, it'll use in process session management by default (unless you override that in the master web.config in c:\windows\microsoft.net....

Comment: It bombs immediately after. As in I put the values in Session_Start, then F10 to the next method call with is the OnInit, and the second line it bombs requesting the value from session. So basically as soon as it leaves the Session_Start the values are gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BREAKPOINTS!

I had breakpoints set in the constructor methods of the base page, and the main page, as well as the Session_Start and the OnInit. A coworker deleted all breakpoints in the debugger and the problem dissappeared!

Ugh!

Comment: LOL...can't see the wood for the trees :) Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Unbelievable, just had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same thing with a breakpoint at a variable instantiation and page load setting some session values.  Running Windows 7 / VS2010.  When I disable the breakpoint it is then able to load the session state.