# How to determine which usercontrol to be loaded to a div at runtime

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am creating a master page for admin-side of my application, which is using asp.net 4.0 framework and webforms. I have different user controls for sidemenu in different pages. I need to determine which user control is to be loaded at runtime only. I thought of using jquery ajax for this. Can anyone help me on this?
I tried the following jquery but this is alert 'error occured'

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Ready");
    // $(".admin_side_menu").load("Shared/AdminManageDataSideMenu.ascx");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Shared/AdminManageDataSideMenu.ascx",
        contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            // var object = JSON.parse(data);
            alert("success" + data);
            (".admin_side_menu").append(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            alert("Error Occured!");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: what will be the criteria of deciding which control to render?

Comment: There is no specific condition for this. It is predefined that which aspx pages should need which user control. I shall edit my post with a jquery part.

Comment: in the XMLHttpRequest object you should be able to get more info on the error, something that actually tries to describe what went wrong. "Error Occured!" doesn't say much about what kind of problem  you are getting, also if you are only getting html would it not be petter with type GET and not POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to make an `ashx` handler that will return you the user control like

```
public class FooHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(RenderPartialToString("AdminManageDataSideMenu.ascx"));
    }

    private string RenderPartialToString(string controlName)
    {
        Page page = new Page();
        Control control = page.LoadControl(controlName);
        page.Controls.Add(control);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);

        return writer.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

now you can call the handler via jquery like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Foo.ashx",
        contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {               
            alert("success" + data);
            $(".admin_side_menu").append(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            alert("Error Occured!");
        }
    });
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4597341/413670

Comment: Thanks. But the session values used in the user control is throwing an error "Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration."

Comment: @SujaShyam i hope you dont have this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/4258724/413670 also have a look at this link http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Comment: Implementing IRequiresSessionState in the handler solved that issue. Struck with another issue at HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
Error: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Comment: it will be more appropriate if you make another question you will have more chances of getting it answered

Comment: I got the solution by making sight changes to RenderPartialToString function. This link was helpful : http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/01/02/Load-aspnet-web-user-control-using-jQuery-and-web-method.aspx